# Per-use pricing on Google Cloud SQL for few minutes every hour?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Let's say I release an app that gets mild traffic throughout the day, but it is really spread across the day (i.e. 5 minutes out of every hour, arbitrarily spread across the hour too)

How does Google Cloud per-use pricing calculate this?

The documentation states that it rounds up to the hour- but is that a total out of every month or at some other interval?

Also- what exactly is *use*. Even within those 5 minutes of use, individual queries could take milliseconds and actually result in just a few seconds altogether. Which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The per-use prices only apply to the duration the Cloud SQL instance is on (rounded to 1h). An instance is turned off if there are no connections for 15 minutes. Any connection made by authorized App Engine apps or from authorized networks will spin up an instance that is off. While an instance is on the price is the same no matter what is the load (+some charges for I/Os but those limits are harder to hit).

The case you are describing, when an instance is access every few minutes every hour will keep the instance up for intervals of 15 minutes but the round up to 1h will cause lots of hours or charges. :-( If the gaps between database access are large than 1 hour (if the traffic has some strong diurnal patter with no access for many hours; or if the front-end is doing efficient at caching the popular content, perhaps using Memcache if on App Engine) then the per-use will provide substantial savings.